# Difference between Apache Ignite SQL and Scan Query?

Tags: ignite

I'm wondering what's the difference between Ignite SQL and Scan Query, including but not limited to:

1. What are strengths and weaknesses of them?
2. Does Scan Query support Index like SQL?
3. Is there any query optimization for SQL/Scan Query specifically?
4. Performance comparison between them?
5. Ignite SQL make use of H2 database to query cache, does Scan Query do it this way too? What's the way of Scan Query if not?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SqlQuery`

- (+) Can provide better performance with proper indexes
- (+) Full power of SQL: Joins, aggregations, groupings
- (-) Requires `QueryEntity` configuration
- (-) Consumes more memory for indexes and internal data structures

`ScanQuery`

- (+) In some cases, more flexible, since filter and transformer can contain arbitrary code
- (-) Always performs full cache scan (does not use indexes in any way)
- (-) Requires filter and transformer code (classes) to be deployed to the server nodes

I would say that SQL is the default choice for most use cases. ScanQuery is useful when filter/transformer logic can't be expressed in SQL and/or require custom method calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's very helpful, but I noticed I have to define index type for Scan Query using CacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(). Why I have to define index type for Scan Query even through it doesn't make use of index?

Comment: @Henrik You don’t need to define indexed types for a scan query. You _do_ need to do so (or have an equivalent) to enable SQL support.

Comment: @StephenDarlington You are right, I see this code in CacheQueryExample and it's only for text query